# Convert dataframe to flat structure

Tags: python

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```html
ID | A   | B     | C     |
--------------------------
1  | car | house | 500   |
1  | bike| flat  | 300   |
2  | car | flat  | 400   |
2  | bike| flat  | 1500  |
```

I will need to create a **flat structure** which looks like the following:

```html
ID | A1  | B1    | C1    | A2   | B2   | C2   |
-----------------------------------------------
1  | car | house | 500   | bike | flat | 300  |
2  | car | flat  | 400   | bike | flat | 1500 |
```

I tried set_index.T, but I wasn't able to receive the requested flat structure.

Comment: shall I ask how did you connect the run code snippet in your question ? sounds interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,8))
```